# Conditional column format in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I need to format a repot in SQL*Plus based on the length of values returned and the length of column name (in my case it is "heads_results").

Result of the select statement:

```
head_results
**********************************************************
value_1 
value_11
value_222222222
value_99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

I would need to format the length of column "head_results" based on the biggest length values returned on any row (in this case `length('value_99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999')`).
In case of no value returned or if the biggest length values returned is less than `length ('head_results')` then to format the length of column_name to its length.

Is it possible in SQL*Plus?

Comment: If you aren't restricted to SQL\*Plus, you could explore [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html) and its `set sqlformat ansiconsole` command to see if that gets the results you want more simply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a substitution variable and the SQL*Plus `column ... new_value ...` syntax to define its value from a query:

```
column col_width new_value col_width noprint

select greatest(nvl(max(length(head_results)), 0), length('head_results')) as col_width
from your_table;

column head_results format "a&col_width"
```

The query:

- finds the longest value in the table with `max(length(head_results))`;
- defaults that to zero in case there are only nulls (or no data) with `nvl(..., 0)`;
- finds the larger of that value and the fixed string with `greatest(..., length('head_results'))` though you could use the fixed value 12 if you prefer;
- and gives the result of that expression the alias `col_width`.

Then the `column col_width new_value col_width noprint` allows you to use `col_width` as a substitution variable, which inherits the value from the query.

Then the `column head_results format "a&col_width"` sets the column width to the number of characters the query returned, using that substitution variable - the `a&col_width` is translated to `a12`, or `a15`, or `a68`, or whatever.

When you do your actual query that column will be shown with that width.

---

Demo with a dummy table, initially with one short value, the heading width is 12 characters:

```
create table your_table (head_results varchar2(80));
insert into your_table (head_results)
values ('value_1');

1 row inserted.

set termout off
column col_width new_value col_width noprint
select greatest(nvl(max(length(head_results)), 0),
  length('head_results')) as col_width
from your_table;
column head_results format "a&col_width"
set termout on

select head_results from your_table;

HEAD_RESULTS
------------
value_1
```

With a longer value added it gets a bit wider:

```
insert into your_table (head_results)
values ('value_222222222');

1 row inserted.

set termout off
column col_width new_value col_width noprint
select greatest(nvl(max(length(head_results)), 0), length('head_results')) as col_width
from your_table;
column head_results format "a&col_width"
set termout on

select head_results from your_table;

HEAD_RESULTS   
---------------
value_1
value_222222222
```

And with your longest value it's still wide enough:

```
insert into your_table (head_results)
values ('value_99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999');

1 row inserted.

set termout off
column col_width new_value col_width noprint
select greatest(nvl(max(length(head_results)), 0), length('head_results')) as col_width
from your_table;
column head_results format "a&col_width"
set termout on

select head_results from your_table;

HEAD_RESULTS                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------
value_1
value_222222222
value_99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

Comment: The script works fine but if I use the & it is interpreted as substitution variable and for this I need to use SET SCAN OFF but in this case, it says "SP2-0246: Illegal FORMAT string "A"".

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @mikcutu - sorry, I'd only fully tested it in SQL Developer which is generally the same. For some reason SQL\*Plus doesn't like that construct. You could get the entire `a12` or whatever in the hidden query, but enclosing in double-quotes works too, so I've updated to show that. `set scan` is obsolete, but needs to be `on` not `off`; you do need `set define on` which is the default anyway.

Comment: I made few more tests. Indeed, with your example, everything works fine but if I am using an exhaustive SELECT statement, I am getting into the problem where the "&" is interpreted as substitution variable.
In order to pass over this situation, I created a temporary global table as SELECT ...
With this, I managed to pass over the substitution variable problem but, the dinamic definition is not working anymore. The maximum length of the value is 139 while the header underline is 301

Comment: @mikcutu - if your query contains a `&` somewhere in it that you don't want to be treated as a substitution variable then you can use [the `set define` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG073) to change which character is used for substitution variables. Pick a character you never use elsewhere, then use that same character instead of `&` in the `"a&col_width"` part.

Comment: my query does not contain any other "&" in the sentence but it contains "%". I hope it is not considered substitution variable, too.

Comment: No, it isn't. I don't understand what you mean by 'I am getting into the problem where the "&" is interpreted as substitution variable' then.